# Laravel createMany() and saveMany() functions doing multiple insert queries instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, sql-insert

I am using Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1.0. I am trying to save order items through a HasMany/Belongs to relationship (One Order has Many OrderProducts). Although I am using saveMany method I am encountering an N+1 problem. What the code does is gets data from $calculation which is not stored on a DB but rather as a property on the model instance. Then through a foreach i go through each product and create a "local" OrderProduct object. Then after that I want to save it using one query using saveMany.

I've tried switching to createMany() approach but I get the same exact result. I suspected i might be running the saveMany() many times so I logged it and nope it shows only one. I tried feeding it to chatGPT but it didn't help either

The code:

Function where the problem is happening:

```
public function createOrderItems(Order $calculation, Order $order): void
{
    $order_products = [];

    foreach ($calculation->getProducts() as $product) {
        $order_products[] = new OrderProduct([
            'product_id' => $product->product_id,
            'quantity' => $product->quantity,
            'price_with_pdv' => $product->price_with_pdv,
            'price_without_pdv' => $product->price_without_pdv,
            'weight' => $product->weight,
        ]);
    }

    $order->orderProducts()->saveMany($order_products);
}
```

How that function is called
`$this->createOrderItems($calculation, $order);`

orderProducts() relationship (on Order model):

```
public function orderProducts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class);
}
```

This is the telescope log:

```
insert into `order_products` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `price_with_pdv`, `price_without_pdv`, `weight`...  0.33ms  
insert into `order_products` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `price_with_pdv`, `price_without_pdv`, `weight`...  0.34ms  
insert into `order_products` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `price_with_pdv`, `price_without_pdv`, `weight`...  0.50ms  
insert into `order_products` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `price_with_pdv`, `price_without_pdv`, `weight`...  0.30ms  
insert into `order_products` (`product_id`, `quantity`, `price_with_pdv`, `price_without_pdv`, `weight`...  0.45ms
```

If any more code/explanation is needed I'm happy to provide it

Comment: You're doing `new OrderProduct` in your loop, then you're saving it again with `orderProducts()->saveMany($order_products);`. Pick one or the other.

Comment: @aynber Aren't I doing the same as is described in [link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) . Shouldn't $order_products just end up as an array filled with memory allocated Objects that have nothing to do with a database?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Are you getting duplicate rows, or just worried that it's saving one individually? `saveMany` uses a foreach loop to save each model instead of doing a mass insert.

Comment: I didn't know that `saveMany` functioned that way. But yeah I don't have problems with duplicate rows, I just need a mass insert

Comment: I can't remember if `insert()` will do a mass insert or not. You can try it and see

Comment: the eloquent methods won't do any mass insertion as they need to create model instances and save them (for timestamps and events)